# shell cmd transfair windows cmd

Tags: linux, windows, shell, batch-file, command-line

I have a regexp using grep which I use to get the latest directory matching it.
Any chance I get a equivalent command as the one below to work on a windows machine?

```
ls | grep -E "20[0-9]{2}-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]-[0-9]{0,5}" | tail -1
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You can try the PowerShell - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730947.aspx

Comment: is it the date-stamp of the folder or is the date part of the directory name? Can you give a few examples?

Comment: the command is usually triggered from within a normal windows commandline, i think i am not able to start a powershell

Comment: @Stephan Yes it is a timestamp in combination with a magic number eg. 2015-04-02-0938, 2016-06-06-09999, ...

Comment: Take a look to `dir /?`. Check, if `dir /ad -od -tw` sorts correct. If yes, use `for` to get the last line: `for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir -ad -od -tw -b') do set latest=%%a`

Answer (score 0):

Installing [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) will give you a nearly linux like shell environment. When you set the cygwin bin into your windows PATH you can even build the pipe like that in a CMD. I can't say anything about the unix like stuff that newer windowses are supposed to bring along though.

Comment: not exaktly what I am looking for, would really need a windows equivalent